# FileNameMapping "no-version-for-ejb" equivalent for OutputFileNameMapping

Tags: maven-ear-plugin

FileNameMapping is now deprecated after the version 3.0.0 of the maven-ear-plugin.

Is there an equivalent way of using "no-version-for-ejb" with OutputFileNameMapping ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this: [Customizing A Module Filename](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-ear-plugin-3.0.0/examples/customizing-a-module-filename.html)

For me, it worked when omitting the new "outputFileNameMapping" and adding this snippet to "pom.xml" of the EAR project:

```
    <configuration>
       [...]
       <modules>
         <ejbModule>
           <groupId>..artifactGroupId..</groupId>
           <artifactId>..artifactId..</artifactId>
           <bundleFileName>ejbName.jar</bundleFileName>
         </ejbModule>
      </modules>
    </configuration>
```

My sample EAR contained also a Web module. After adding this snippet, the EJB jar had a fixed named, but the WAR file still had the default name built from "groupId-artifactId-version.war".